# Average over summaries and save averaged value with SummaryWriter

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a model in tensor flow and want to evaluate the current model on a dev set. However, this set is too large to evaluate in one step, so I split it up in different batches. Each of these has an accuracy, loss etc. In place of saving the summary of the final batch, as is the case below, I want to save the average value of all these statistics to plot in TensorBoard.

How can this be done, since the output summary is an unreadable string, that I can load into a `tf.Summary` object, but I am unable to create a string from this..

```
summary = tf.Summary()
for batch in batches:
    x_batch, y_batch = zip(*batch)
    feed_dict = { cnn.input_x: x_batch, cnn.input_y: y_batch, cnn.keep_prob: 1.0 }

    step, summaries, loss, accuracy, mae = sess.run(
        [global_step, dev_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy, cnn.mae],
        feed_dict)
    loss_vector.append(loss)
    accuracy_vector.append(accuracy)
    mae_vector.append(mae)
    # read data into Summary object
    summary.MergeFromString(summaries)
time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
loss, accuracy, mae = np.mean(loss_vector), np.mean(accuracy_vector), np.mean(mae_vector)
print("{}: step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}, MAE {:g}".format(time_str, step, loss, accuracy, mae))
if writer:
    # unable to use writer.add_summary(summary, step), does not plot in tensorboard....
    writer.add_summary(summaries, step) # saves only last one :(
```

Comment: You could add a placeholder and assign it the mean of the accuracy on your batches with tf.assign()